# Correct use of “treat”

Tags: grammaticality

My gf always refers to wet cat food as “treat”, as in she’ll say “I gave the cats treat”. This sounds grammatically incorrect to me, but I don’t know the exact reason why. I feel like the correct way to say this is “gave them a treat”, but I’m not sure if they are both correct. An explanation either way would be appreciated!

Comment: Is she a native speaker of English?

Comment: This is not really relevant to the core of the question, but I thought that in the cat-care parlance, *treat* is the term reserved for the intensely flavoured dry items that are offered only occasionally and in small amounts, and not used for wet food (which typically constitutes a meal).

Comment: Sure, I gave them a treat or treats but this will probably be closed. Please read the Help section, top right under the three-bar icon. Thanks. But wet catfood is not called a treat. It's just wet (cat) food.

Comment: Is there a dialect of English where "She gave the cat some treat" is idiomatic?  "treat" as a mass noun?

Comment: ... I'm not aware that 'treat' has been massified, nor that it has the sense 'wet cat food'. **A** treat is a [surprise] special present ... an ice cream, or a trip to the zoo would qualify. But 'a treat' doesn't mean 'an ice cream' etc.

Comment: So in summary you should dump your girlfriend because she's wrong. Or you could view it as a lovable quirk and not mention it, maybe even start saying it yourself.

Comment: Purina has a line of catfood (wet) called Treats. So you gf has gotten the idea that wet cat food is called “treat.” A process in language change.

Comment: Trick or treat. Not a treat. Treat yourself to @StuartF advice not to argue with **a** partner over **a** single letter no matter how right **u** **r**.

Comment: When *treat* is, as is usual, treated as a countable noun, there could be a question of how treats are to be counted when they come in the form of small dry, clearly separated items, as is the case with typical cat treats. Some people may, when speaking of cat treats, count each pellet as a treat, while others may refer to a serving, typically consisting of several pellets, as a treat. If the word is used in the former way, there is very rarely an occasion to say 'a treat', because one normally does not present a cat with only one pellet at a time.

Comment: Bottom line: cat treats are not cat food. In English, you need a treat or treats.

Answer (score 1):

In strictest English grammar it probably should be "*as **a** treat*". However there might be a couple of reasons why your girlfriend says otherwise in this context.

It is common to use the names of certain food groups or types without an article or a determiner - for example, we might say "*I had salad for lunch*", rather than "*for **my** lunch*". We might also say "*would you like dessert?*" rather than "*would you like **a** dessert?*". It's possible that, in some regions or dialects, "treat" is used like 'dessert' or 'pudding'?

We also sometimes use nouns as labels for things, especially in connection with food or diets, and then use the label in isolation - for example, some diets restrict certain foods or food groups but then allow you to have one as a "treat", or even sometimes as a "cheat". Again, it's possible that your girlfriend is using "treat" to refer to the wet cat food as their 'treat food'.

Less likely, but some northern British accents do drop articles and prepositions (eg "*I'm goin' shops*" instead of "*going to the shops*"), but I think you'd have noticed this in her other speech if this was the case.

But really, the best way to find out why your girlfriend says this is to ask her, rather than strangers on the internet. All the best with that!

Comment: "Would you like a desert?" is perfectly idiomatic. I gave my cat a few treats. Or a treat or treats.

Comment: @Lambie I didn't say it wasn't idiomatic. Are you suggesting "would you like desert" is not?

Comment: No, I am saying that this: "We might also say "would you like desert?" rather than "would you like a desert?"."  is not a fact.

Comment: You don't think that we "might also" say that? Well, that's an interesting thought, but you're incorrect.

Comment: No, you give cats treats, not as a treat. That's human: His mum bought  him a cake **as a treat**. The question is about cats. I gave my cat some cooked chicken **as a treat**. And wet cat food is not expressed as treat food.

Comment: @Lambie  Gobi or Sahara?